# clang-format header include guard

Tags: clang-format

I'd like for the `clang-format` to check that each of my headers have the proper include guard.
For example, for the file `dopelib/dopestuff/whatitisyo.h`, I'd like the code to be formatted like this:

```
#ifndef DOPELIB_DOPESTUFF_WHATITISYO_H
#define DOPELIB_DOPESTUFF_WHATITISYO_H

/** Code here. **/

#endif  // DOPELIB_DOPESTUFF_WHATITISYO_H
```

Can `clnag-format` check this structure and make sure that the include guard is there and that it is named appropriately with the file name in the `#ifndef` (sort of what cpplint does)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, `clang-format` doesn't currently support this.

However, you can do exactly this with `clang-tidy` ([documented here](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/)). Invoke it like this:

```
clang-tidy -checks='-*,llvm-header-guard' -fix-errors myIncludeFile.h
```

Explanation:

- The `-*` tells `clang-tidy` to disable all checks
- The `llvm-header-guard` tells `clang-tidy` to enable the check which deals with include guards ([documented here](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/llvm-header-guard.html))
- The `-fix-errors` tells `clang-tidy` to fix any resulting issues, even if it runs into other errors parsing the file

The `llvm-header-guard` expected format of the include-guards is exactly what you requested above; for example the file mydir/myfile.h would use MYDIR_MYFILE_H. I don't see any documentation which actually specifies that this is the format it uses, but I've verified at least version 6.0.0 does use that format.

Also see: [clang include fixer](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/include-fixer.html), which does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution may not work if

- The project has a different file structure
- Uses some extensions that clang does not understand

I have a script here: https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter/blob/master/devtools/include_guard_fix.py